# SignalR in windows forms

Tags: signalr

SignalR is very interesting and impressive in real time web applications. Now I am doing a simple chat applciation using windows forms.

Whenever, I use ".wait()", it threw an error 'one or more errors' and while invoke the message from text box, there is an error 'start must be call before send'.

I don't know where i made mistake. I tried many of the solutions. But it doesn't work. Everything is perfect in web and console applications.

Can anyone help me?
Can you give some examples with how it works...?
I couldn't see any samples of signalR in windows forms.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you update your question to make it easier for us to understand how best to help you. For example "it threw an error 'one or more error'" doesn't tell me very much about what you were doing and what specific errors you encountered. The more information you can give about the problems you're facing the better.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do a SignalR Client in Windows Forms Appliation then check this [post](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2012/12/testing-signalr-in-wpf-console-and.html)(http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2012/12/testing-signalr-in-wpf-console-and.html) on how to do client side SignalR in WPF application in VB.  With similar approach I guess you could make Signalr client working in Windows Forms Application.